# Getting world space vertex coordinates in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

I'd like to get world space coordinates for a specific mesh vertex. [Transform.TransformPoint()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) seems to be what I need however I'm unable to get the correct position.

In the scene I have an object called "head" at Pos (0, 0, 0) Scale (0.03, 0.03, 0.03) and I'm trying to get the position of vertex id 590 in order to spawn another object at that specific location.

```
Mesh mesh = GameObject.Find ("head").GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
Vector3 newPos = transform.TransformPoint (vertices [590]);
Debug.Log (newPos);
```

The value of newPos is not on the head object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the transform from the script's `GameObject` rather than the "head" `GameObject`.

```
GameObject gameObject = GameObject.Find ("head");
Mesh mesh = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
Vector3 newPos = gameObject.transform.TransformPoint (vertices [590]);
Debug.Log (newPos);
```

Also, if your "head" object has skinned animations then just using `TransformPoint` will miss it.

You need to first create a snapshot of your skinned mesh using [SkinnedMeshRenderer.BakeMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SkinnedMeshRenderer.BakeMesh.html) to obtain the vertex position after skeleton animation, before passing it to `TransformPoint`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Using gameObject.transform and works as expected! E: and also thanks for the heads up on using skinned meshes, I might have run into that issue at one point.

Comment: @stephane - your answer is helping with my sanity. I am stuck on a similar issue where I have a world point and want to force a skinned point into that world point. But going from world to skinned local is perplexing me. I am using BakeMesh without issue, but I am unclear on how to use the baked mesh along with InverseTransformPoint. Any tips?